# Setting up Google Domains DNS to work with Mailgun MX Records

Tags: dns, mailgun

I am trying to use Mailgun to receive emails at subdomains of my email. Like at `hi@bob.stage.example.com`. I added the MX records as instructed by Mailgun, however I cannot get it to completely verify. The MX records stay orange with an "!".

I use Google Apps for the main domain `example.com`, but not for any subdomains.

What do you think I can do to get Google Domains & Mailgun to agree on what MX records to use?

Answer (score 11):

In Google DNS, you need to use the same entry, but with two "sub-entries" for the MX records.  Enter the first mail server:

```
mxa.mailgun.org
```

Then click the '+' symbol to the right of the field.  When the second text field appears, enter the second MX record:

```
mxb.mailgun.org
```

Google will automatically prioritize both of entries at 10.

Here is how it appears on the screen:
[image: Google DNS screenshot].

Comment: I've followed this answer exactly as stated above, and have the same results as the picture, yet I still can't get the MX records to verify. Any one confirm that this solves their issue? @Kelly Orr

Comment: @tman091: Confirm the time to live (TTL) for the domain name and assure that you are waiting long enough for the update to occur.

Comment: Make sure you add your subdomain ex: `mg` at the *host* field, forgot to do that so my email was not validating

Answer (score 2):

For Google Domains, you need to add the subdomain `bob.stage` MX records as a Custom resource records.

In the `name` field, you'll need to add `bob.stage` and in the `Mail server` field, add `mxa.mailgun.org`. Same thing for `mxb.mailgun.org`.

Comment: Hello there, but when I add "mxb.mailgun.org", error appears as "Record already in use". Do you have any idea bout this?

Comment: @weefwefwqg3 just click on "+" and  it will show two text boxes in order to put both